# BootStrap element timepicker with ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i need help , i want to use BootStrap element timepicker with ASP.NET C# page , i add all references in master Page and it's work when i use HTML Code but now i want to use as ASP.net how to use Timepicker with Asp:Textbox?
find code below

HTML Code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-11">

<label for="timepicker1">Enter:</label>

<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
<input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="form-control" />
<span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following for the ASP.NET TextBox:

```
<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" data-provide="timepicker" CssClass="form-control timepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
```

Then in the script, do the following:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#txtTime").timepicker({
        showInputs: false //Set showInputs to false
    });
})
</script>
```

[image: sample_timepicker]

Please check here to download the files: https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/releases

Answer (score 0):

The secret to getting the control to work is: data-provide="timepicker". This is required when you set: runat="server".

Ex:

```
<script>
   $(function () {
      $(".timepicker").timepicker({
         minuteStep: 15
      });
   })
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="StartTime" data-provide="timepicker" CssClass="timepicker" runat="server" />
```